# Arduino Nano Every Vin 5V fixes I2c problems

Tags: arduino-nano, i2c, usb, voltage

I had problems with connecting my devices via I2C. The "requestfrom" constantly hanged and the endtransmission sometimes gave NACK responses.

After disconnecting the devices from 12V and powering one of them via USB (vin with which it was connected to the other arduino's became 3.8V) they stopped misbehaving and worked together in harmony.

How is this possible? Am I missing something? An Arduino Nano Every should be driven between 6-21V?

All devices are "Arduino Nano Every"'s. They used to get 12V directly on Vin and are connected together in a chain by Vin,GND,A5(SCK),A4(SDA)

The master is in the middle of the chain so that the distance is max 20cm.

I also tried powering them via vin with 9V and 5V. Had the same issue.

Already big thanks for the help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128425/discussion-on-question-by-roel-arduino-nano-every-vin-5v-fixes-i2c-problems).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO... In the datasheet it says you should use 7-21V on VIN. This gave the problem. I powered the arduinos directly from 5V on the vin. This fixed all I2C problems. Haven't had any problems anymore after changing this.

cheers to all.

Comment: You're saying that the voltage on the input side of regulator... causes the internal pull-ups to change value inside of a chip on the output side of the regulator?

Comment: it doesn't make sense

Comment: Not the way I'm reading it currently anyway.

Comment: No i'm saying that I THINK there is something wrong with the voltage regulator of the every and that a higher voltage actually goes through. When using a higher voltage on the I2C bus the pull up resistors are not the right Ohm to give a good data signal. That is why it constantly quit the connection after some time.

Comment: Pure guess. But it fixed my problems to just power it via 5V on the vin.

Comment: I see, It would be good to make clear that you found that it helped (empirically) and that the business about "actually makes the resistances..." is really speculative.  It still doesn't make sense to me, but I'll grant you something may have changed.  As long as whoever reading this understands what's guess and what's not, good deal.

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: To my thinking, yes.  You're saying something factual about what you did and what you observed correlated to it.  You removed the bits that seemingly had no fact or theory behind them and had no indication that they were, as you put it "pure guess."  I call that an improvement.